# Where does $X_n$ converge to?

Tags: random-variable, density-function, convergence

Let $ X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots $ be independent random variables and let $ X_n $ have a probability density fucntion (PDF) defined by

$ f_{X_n}(x) \quad=\quad \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\nu\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)} \;\left(1+\frac{a_n^2 x^2}{\nu}\right)^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}\;a_n \,. $

Where $ a_n\to\infty $.

I want to study convergence when $ v = 1 $ and $ v = 3 $. Is it correct to think that, if $ v = 1 $ then $ X_n $ converges in probability to 0 and if $ v = 3 $ then $ X_n $ converges in quadratic mean to 0?

Comment: This is a [generalized student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Generalized_Student's_t-distribution). It has no defined variance for $\nu =1$ and it has finite variance for $\nu = 3$.

Comment: So neither case converges? That doesn't make sense to me, both should converge

Comment: In the case $\nu = 1$ the variance is infinite but it still converges in probability (there will just be always some remaining non-zero probability that the variable is infinitely large, but the proportion of the probability that the variable is within some arbitrary small range around zero can be made as large as you want). In the case $\nu = 3$ the variance is finite. What would happen to the variance of variable (with finite variance) if you scale it? Could you make the variance as small as you like?

Comment: I'd say yes, which would mean case $\nu = 3$ converges in quadratic mean. Correct?